# .txtファイルを.csvファイルに変換したい

Tags: python, python3, pandas, csv

python3.6環境下で以下の.csvファイルを出力しました。これをカンマ(`,`)区切りの.csvファイルに変換したいのですがうまくいきません。zepp.csv の一行1列目の要素には `a b c d e f` が格納されており、区切りが空白なのです。これらをカンマ区切りで `a, b, c, d, e, f` に訂正するアルゴリズムを各成分に対して適用するコードが書きたいです。以下に試してみたコードを並べます。

```
import csv
with open(zepp.csv, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
```

pandasも使用したのですが思い通りに動きませんでした。

Answer (score 6):

`writer`オブジェクトを生成しただけで、ファイルに書き込む処理が無いですね。

例外処理などを省略していますが（＝ファイルが存在しない場合や半角スペース区切りではない場合を考慮していませんが）、以下のようなコードでいいと思います。

```
import csv
import os

os.rename('zepp.csv', 'backup_zepp.csv')
with open('backup_zepp.csv') as fin, open('zepp.csv', 'w') as fout:
    o=csv.writer(fout)
    for line in fin:
        o.writerow(line.split())
```

Answer (score 6):

元のTXTファイルにヘッダ行が無く、CSVファイルにもヘッダ行・Index列が共に必要無いと仮定すると、**pandas**では

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_table('zepp.txt', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
df.to_csv('zepp.csv', index=False, header=False)
```

で良いかと思います